# kendo grid ui editable configuration

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I just want to ask if somebody knows how to set the kendo grid to editable true or false on button click.? I can set the grid to editable true if it is set to false but, I can't set it back to editable false. Your response is highly appreciated. :)

```
$('.k-grid-add').on('click',function(){
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: dataSource,
          navigatable: true,
          pageable: true,
          height: 430,
          toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
          columns: [
              "ProductName", {
              field: "UnitPrice",
              title: "Unit Price",
              format: "{0:c}",
              width: 110
          }, {
              field: "UnitsInStock",
              title: "Units In Stock",
              width: 110
          }, {
              field: "Discontinued",
              width: 110
          }, {
              command: "destroy",
              title: "&nbsp;",
              width: 90
          }],
          editable: true
      });
});

$('.k-grid-cancel-changes').on('click',function(){
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: dataSource,
          navigatable: true,
          pageable: true,
          height: 430,
          toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
          columns: [
              "ProductName", {
              field: "UnitPrice",
              title: "Unit Price",
              format: "{0:c}",
              width: 110
          }, {
              field: "UnitsInStock",
              title: "Units In Stock",
              width: 110
          }, {
              field: "Discontinued",
              width: 110
          }, {
              command: "destroy",
              title: "&nbsp;",
              width: 90
          }],
          editable: false
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically changing the editable option of the Grid is not supported.

You need to either re-initialize the whole Grid with the new settings.

Or you will have to create template column that based on your condition displays a button that puts the row into edit mode (invoke the **[editRow](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-editRow)** method of the Grid). Regarding the conditional logic and how to perform it is covered in [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) topic.